# Error installing scipy library through pip on python 3: "compile failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, pip

I'm trying to install scipy library through pip on python 3.3.5. By the end of the script, i'm getting this error:

> Command /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9r7808-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
>   Storing debug log for failure in /Users/dan/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Have you looked at `/Users/dan/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
  Running command /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in   ['/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib'] NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: blas_mkl_info: libraries mkl,vml,guide not found. So is this a dependency issue? How can I get these libraries?

Answer (score 18):

I was getting the same thing when using pip, I went to the install and it pointed to the following dependencies.

`sudo apt-get install python python-dev libatlas-base-dev gcc gfortran g++`

Comment: I was getting the OP's error, but using Python-pip 2.7. installing these dependencies allowed me to install.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install scipy
```

Worked for me! Had the same exact problem!

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the source from https://github.com/scipy/scipy and was able to build and install it successfully using python 3.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users meeting similar error and arriving here: You can install scipy as explained in [Scipy website installation instructions](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)